# Browsing througfh ibm mq messages with a specific date or time or date range

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to retrieve messages from IBM mq with a specific time range for example messages that were put over the past 2 hours or from 0500 to 0600 or between dates or 2 days back. if possible please provide a sample java code. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you written so far?  Or are you looking to pay a consultant to do it for you?

Basically, you have to browse with a lock, and check the message's timestamp to see if it is in the time range, if yes, perform a destructive MQGET otherwise browse the next message.